# How to translate this "Group By" MySQL query to Spring's JPA / CrudRepository interface

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

We have a MySQL table

```
id | username | state | action
 1 |  Ringo   |   CA  |  sell
 2 |  Paul    |   CA  |  sell
 3 |  John    |   CA  |  buy
 4 |  Ringo   |   CA  |  sell   
 5 |  Ringo   |   MA  |  sell
```

And we like to get the latest "sell" actions of each user in "CA" (so in this example, for Ringo, we like to get record number 4, but not record number 1).

In MySQL, we can do something like that (I bet this can be improved):

```
select * from actions where id in (
   select max(id) from actions 
   where action = "sell"
   and state = "CA"
   group by username
)
```

We were trying to do it in Spring's `CrudRepository` in several ways, but none seems to do what we like. 
Here are some of the things we have tried:

```
public interface ActionsRepository extends CrudRepository<ActionEntry, Long>{   
List<ActionEntry> findDistinctUserNameByStateAndActionOrderByIdDesc(String state, String action);
List<ActionEntry> findTopByStateAndActionOrderByIdDesc(String namespace, String action);
```

Is there a way to do it in JPA?

Comment: Have you tried adding top 1 like `List<ActionEntry> findTop1DistinctUserNameByStateAndActionOrderByIdDesc(String state, String action);`

Comment: @SudhirOjha adding `Top1` seems to bring only one entry, so it is not good enought

Comment: For more complex queries, use the `@Query` annotation to define the query manually. https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-query